# Jenkins Issue: How to get the list of files from a shared location using Java

Tags: java, jenkins

Runnig from Jekins --- I am getting a **issue indicating "Parameter 'directory' is not a directory"** while using the following. please suggest an option to get the list of files from the shared folder.

```
public List<File> clickDownloadExcel() {
            File dir = new File("//CHOFILE/Public/QETeam/AutomationDownloads");
   log.info("**************************************************"+dir.getPath());

                String[] extensions = new String[] { "csv", "xls", "xml" };
                List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
                return files;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try "//CHOFILE//Public//QETeam//AutomationDownloads" ?

Comment: Yes i tried, Locally its working fine, In fact while running from jenkins i am getting the error "Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Comment: You expect to be able to reach a network drive using a Java filesystem path. That won't work on Windows. It expects a drive letter followed by a path, or a relative path.

Comment: Could you please give a solution how i should get the relative path

Comment: @RealSkeptic you are right, I guess he needs the relative path.

Comment: A relative path won't work because first you need to set the current working directory to that file system, and then you'll run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can give you the working directory. Then change the relative path according to the way you need.

```
private String getWorkingChar(){
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String workingChar = "/";

    if (workingDir.indexOf("\\") != -1) {
        workingChar = "\\";
    }

    return workingChar;
}
```

This is how I get my webapps directory. :

```
public String getWebappsDirectory(){
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String workingChar = getWorkingChar();

    //other deploy
    return workingDir + workingChar + "webapps" + workingChar;

    //main deploy
    //return workingDir + workingChar + ".." + workingChar + "webapps" + workingChar;
}
```

Comment: I have used system.getproperty("file.seperator") as well, and it didnt work

Comment: Did you get the webapps directory ?

Comment: Just an FYI, I am running a test from jenkins and which tried to read a file from the Shared location. That is where i am getting this error

Comment: 13:24:24.359 [pool-1-thread-1] [chrome] INFO  RevenueDetails - *****************************************************************\\CHOFILE\Public\QETeam\AutomationDownloads
13:24:24.740 [pool-1-thread-1] [chrome] ERROR TestLogger - FAILED revenue.RevenueSanityTest.tc_003exportResultsFor3ProjectTypes-ch.latest : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory<br>org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFilesParameters(FileUtils.java:545)

Comment: Ok, let me think what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(ext);
    File dir = new File("//CHOFILE/Public/QETeam/AutomationDownloads");     
    String[] list = dir.list(filter);
    int numbFile = list.length;
```

Comment: what is ext parameter

Comment: @vini007 it's your extension files

Comment: Should i need to add anything in POM for GenericExtFilter

Comment: @vini007 just library of GenericExtFilter

Comment: GenericFileFilter, this is the right one ! am i correct

Comment: @vini007 take a look at this [http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.erlang/sonar-erlang-plugin/0.1/org/sonar/plugins/erlang/cover/GenericExtFilter.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.erlang/sonar-erlang-plugin/0.1/org/sonar/plugins/erlang/cover/GenericExtFilter.java)

Comment: It seems an issue with reading the folder path from shared drive

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because the shared folder was not set the pemission properly. When my admin the permission to that shared folder, it worked correctly